# DbUnit and JSON column type support

Tags: java, mysql, testing, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I'm wondering what's the best possible way to make DbUnit work with MySQL's JSON(B) type columns? We do have such columns here and there and whenever I am trying to feed the test data from XML file via `@DatabaseSetup` I get the NoSuchColumnException which prevents me form making of any sensible integration tests with entities or repos that deals with JSON:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: assistant_event.AEV_CONTEXT -  (Non-uppercase input column: aev_context) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.
```

I get that this is because my `AEV_CONTEXT` column didn't get recognized because, well, it's a JSON column:

```
@Type(type = "json")
@Column(name = "aev_context", columnDefinition = "json")
private Context context;
```

However, I'm getting a hard time while trying to workaround it. And, what's even more odd, I couldn't find such workaround anywhere here either! In fact, I don't event know if that's more Hibernate or DbUnit thing.

**Is it really only me had this problem so far? Any advice would be much appreciated!**

Oh, and in case you wondering, that's how I get JSON support for Hibernate:

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case someone needs it this is the Java version of [@Aleksi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559173/355438) for the PostgreSQL JSONB datatype:

```
import org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.AbstractDataType;
import org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DataType;
import org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DataTypeException;
import org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.TypeCastException;
import org.dbunit.ext.postgresql.PostgresqlDataTypeFactory;
import org.postgresql.util.PGobject;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class NewPostgresqlDataTypeFactory extends PostgresqlDataTypeFactory {
    @Override
    public DataType createDataType(int sqlType, String sqlTypeName) throws DataTypeException {
        if (sqlTypeName.equals("jsonb")) {
            return new JsonbDataType();
        } else {
            return super.createDataType(sqlType, sqlTypeName);
        }
    }

    public static class JsonbDataType extends AbstractDataType {

        public JsonbDataType() {
            super("jsonb", Types.OTHER, String.class, false);
        }

        @Override
        public Object typeCast(Object obj) throws TypeCastException {
            return obj.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getSqlValue(int column, ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, TypeCastException {
            return resultSet.getString(column);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSqlValue(Object value,
                                int column,
                                PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException, TypeCastException {
            final PGobject jsonObj = new PGobject();
            jsonObj.setType("json");
            jsonObj.setValue(value == null ? null : value.toString());

            statement.setObject(column, jsonObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One potential solution is to define your own DataTypeFactory and use that. I did it to support the PostgreSQL JSONB datatype, something similar could be made for MySQL.

```
class NewPostgresqlDataTypeFactory : PostgresqlDataTypeFactory() {
    override fun createDataType(sqlType: Int, sqlTypeName: String?): DataType {
        return when (sqlTypeName) {
            "jsonb" -> return JsonbDataType()
            else -> super.createDataType(sqlType, sqlTypeName)
        }
    }

    class JsonbDataType : AbstractDataType("jsonb", Types.OTHER, String::class.java, false) {
        override fun typeCast(obj: Any?): Any {
            return obj.toString()
        }

        override fun getSqlValue(column: Int, resultSet: ResultSet): Any {
            return resultSet.getString(column)
        }

        override fun setSqlValue(value: Any?, column: Int, statement: PreparedStatement) {
            val jsonObj = PGobject()
            jsonObj.type = "json"
            jsonObj.value = value?.toString()
            statement.setObject(column, jsonObj)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Ilya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55839637/22253592), here is the similar solution for H2 JSON datatype:

```java
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.AbstractDataType;
import org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DataType;
import org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DataTypeException;
import org.dbunit.ext.h2.H2DataTypeFactory;
import org.h2.value.Value;
import org.h2.value.ValueJson;

public class CustomH2DataTypeFactory extends H2DataTypeFactory {

        @Override
        public DataType createDataType(int sqlType, String sqlTypeName, String tableName, String columnName)
            throws DataTypeException {
            if (sqlType == 1111 && sqlTypeName.toLowerCase().startsWith("json")) {
                return new JsonDataType();
            } else {
                return super.createDataType(sqlType, sqlTypeName, tableName, columnName);
            }
        }

        public class JsonDataType extends AbstractDataType {

            public JsonDataType() {
                super("json", Types.OTHER, String.class, false);
            }

            @Override
            public Object typeCast(Object value) {
                return value.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getSqlValue(int column, ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
                return resultSet.getString(column);
            }

            @Override
            public void setSqlValue(Object value, int column, PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException {
                Value object = ValueJson.fromJson(value.toString());
                statement.setObject(column, object);
            }
        }
    }
```